# Why does multithreaded execution give such a small gain?

Tags: multithreading, rust

To measure the performance gain from multithreading, I wrote two functions: `single` - summation in one thread, `reduction` - each thread summarizes its part, after which the main thread summarizes the result. I am running this task on a computer with `16` cores available. I decided to do the work in 10 threads so that each thread was loaded the same way.

`single` is executed on average in `0.42`secs, `reduction` on average in `0.23`secs, that is, the performance gain was about `1.83`, when I expected an acceleration of at least 5-7 times. If I run reduction on `4` threads, the performance gain will be `1.78` times. This is very strange to me. What am I doing wrong or why can't I get a normal performance boost?

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering::Relaxed},
        mpsc, Arc,
    },
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::{Duration, Instant},
};

const THREADS_COUNT: usize = 10;

fn single(arr: &Vec<u32>) -> u32 {
    let mut sum: u32 = 0;
    for i in arr {
        sum += i;
    }
    sum
}

fn reduction(arr: Arc<Vec<u32>>, threads_count: usize) -> u32 {
    let mut sum = 0;

    let length_child_arr = (arr.len() as f32 / threads_count as f32).ceil() as usize;

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    for i in 1..threads_count {
        let cur_arr = Arc::clone(&arr);
        let start = i * length_child_arr;
        let finish = start + length_child_arr;

        let cur_tx = tx.clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut sum = 0;
            for j in &cur_arr[start..(finish).min(cur_arr.len())]{
                sum += *j;
            }
            cur_tx.send(sum).unwrap();
        });
    }

    for j in 0..length_child_arr {
        sum += arr[j];
    }

    for _ in 1..threads_count {
        sum += rx.recv().unwrap();
    }

    sum
}

fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    let mut root_arr = Vec::new();
    let arr_size: usize = 1_000_000_000;

    for _ in 0..arr_size {
        root_arr.push(1);
    }

    let start = Instant::now();
    let ans1 = single(&root_arr);
    println!(
        "Single version {}secs, answer {ans1}",
        start.elapsed().as_secs_f32()
    );

    let arr2 = Arc::new(root_arr);
    let arr3 = Arc::clone(&arr2);
    let arr4 = Arc::clone(&arr3);

    let start = Instant::now();
    let ans2 = atomic(arr2, THREADS_COUNT);
    println!(
        "Atomic version {}secs, answer {ans2}",
        start.elapsed().as_secs_f32()
    );

    let start = Instant::now();
    let ans3 = reduction(arr3, THREADS_COUNT);
    println!(
        "Reduct version {}secs, answer {ans3}",
        start.elapsed().as_secs_f32()
    );
}
```

**What was I trying to do?**

I understand that I can't get a 10x increase due to overhead.
I think there are some synchronization overhead in Arc (like mutex for example, I do not know), so I use slices in threads. This helped, but it's still too small an increase (before using slices, the increase was 1.2-1.3), but what should I do in this situation?

I also thought that in the reduction function it takes a lot of time to create threads, so I paused after creating all the threads and waited for about 5 seconds, and then started measuring the time, but I got about the same results on both 10 threads and 4 threads.

Maybe it's the channels? But this idea is refuted by the increased performance with an increase in the number of threads from 4 to 10.

I also thought that the thread might not be naive, but the rust book explicitly says that every thread in rust is a native thread.

I understand that this may not be the best use of multithreading, but I wrote a similar program in C++ using OpenMP, then there is a much greater performance gain.

Comment: How is the `atomic` function defined, or did you forget to remove it from the benchmark below?

Comment: _"I wrote a similar program in C++ using OpenMP"_ Might be worth showing that one too. Although it all seems like an attempt at parallelizing an operation which is much too simple.

Comment: I highly recommend using a microbenchmark crate like criterion to test this. At the same time, I recommend using a library like rayon for the actual parallelization of what looks to me like an embarrassingly parallel problem. Rayon will split your input into evenly sized chunks in a way which does not require locking (split_at_mut, for example), and decides on a optimal chunk size for your hardware and input size.

Comment: Did you make sure to compile in release mode?

Comment: Did you get a better **speedup** in other C++/OpenMP or a better **performance**? Because I tried using `rayon` via simply doing `arr.par_iter().sum()`, and got the same performance as your `reduction()` method. Are you sure it isn't simply the case the Rust managed to optimize the single threaded version like crazy? Did you actually measure throughput of OpenMP vs threaded Rust and figured out that Rust was slower?

Comment: @Finomnis, yes, you're right, rust is just very well optimized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The limiting factor in your computation is memory throughput speed, so more cores will only give you a very small speedup.

---

**Long answer:**

To showcase that it is neither the `Arc` nor the `channel`, let me rewrite your code without them:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
    thread,
    time::Instant,
};

use rayon::prelude::*;

const THREADS_COUNT: usize = 16;

fn single(arr: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    let mut sum: u32 = 0;
    for i in arr {
        sum += i;
    }
    sum
}

fn reduction(arr: &[u32], threads_count: usize) -> u32 {
    let total_sum = AtomicU32::new(0);

    let length_child_arr = (arr.len() as f32 / threads_count as f32).ceil() as usize;

    thread::scope(|s| {
        for i in 1..threads_count {
            let start = i * length_child_arr;
            let finish = start + length_child_arr;
            let total_sum = &total_sum;
            s.spawn(move || {
                let mut sum = 0;
                for j in &arr[start..(finish).min(arr.len())] {
                    sum += j;
                }
                total_sum.fetch_add(sum, Ordering::Relaxed);
            });
        }

        let mut sum = 0;
        for j in 0..length_child_arr {
            sum += arr[j];
        }
        total_sum.fetch_add(sum, Ordering::Relaxed);
    });

    total_sum.load(Ordering::Relaxed)
}

fn par_iters_rayon(arr: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    arr.par_iter().sum()
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr = Vec::new();
    let arr_size: usize = 1_000_000_000;

    for _ in 0..arr_size {
        arr.push(1);
    }

    for _ in 0..2 {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let ans = single(&arr);
        println!(
            "Single version {}secs, answer {ans}",
            start.elapsed().as_secs_f32()
        );
    }

    let start = Instant::now();
    let ans = reduction(&arr, THREADS_COUNT);
    println!(
        "Reduct version {}secs, answer {ans}",
        start.elapsed().as_secs_f32()
    );

    let start = Instant::now();
    let ans = par_iters_rayon(&arr);
    println!(
        "Rayon version {}secs, answer {ans}",
        start.elapsed().as_secs_f32()
    );
}
```

```
Single version 0.121125296secs, answer 1000000000
Single version 0.119573295secs, answer 1000000000
Reduct version 0.092172secs, answer 1000000000
Rayon version 0.090481296secs, answer 1000000000
```

What I've done:

- replace `Arc` with references and `thread::scope`
- replace collecting `channel` with `AtomicU32` (almost zero overhead on x86/x64)
- make all the argument types `&[u32]` (is best practice, `&Vec<u32>` only offers disadvantages against it)
- change `THREADS_COUNT` to `16` (because that's the core count on my machine)
- add a `rayon` based implementation

The times are still very close. The `rayon` based implementation is slightly faster, and this one will probably be our golden standard. `rayon` is highly optimized, especially for built-in functions like `.par_iter().sum()`.

So while I don't have a definitive answer about what causes the behavior you see, I suspect that this problem is not CPU bound. I suspect it's memory throughput bound, and adding more cores doesn't yield much of an improvement because the RAM simply can't provide data any faster.

We can do the math: In my Rayon version, we have `1,000,000 items`, and they get computed in `0.090481296 seconds`. So we are processing `11,052,007,919.95729 items/s`, or `11 Gitems/s`. With `4 bytes` per item, we have roughly `44 GBytes/s`. According to the benchmark of my machine on [userbenchmark.com](https://www.userbenchmark.com/), my memory has a throughput of `multi-core read 46.6 GBytes/s`. So yes, it's the RAM that's limiting us.

The same benchmark tells me that my memory can do `single-core read 32.3 GBytes/s`. If we do the math in reverse, you can see that `1,000,000,000 items * 4 bytes/item / 32.3 GBytes/s = 0.1238 seconds`, which is **very** close to the actual numbers I see.

I can't tell you why the C++/OpenMP version scales better without seeing any code. However, I suspect this is a red herring; I don't think that the OpenMP version is **faster** than the `rayon` version, I rather suspect that the C++ single-core version is **slower** than the Rust single-core version. So it's not a better speedup, but a greater reduction of speed for the C++ single core version.

To verify this, please actually measure `items/second` for all of those versions and compare them against each other, not just the speedup. Speedup means nothing if the single-core version is slow.

Comment: You might also want to try processing in chunks (Rayon's `par_chunks` etc) as iterating over singular elements can be bottlenecked by scheduling.

Comment: @PitaJ See my edit - the math says we are already maxing out the RAM bus.

Comment: @PitaJ `arr.par_chunks(1024).map(|e| e.iter().sum::<u32>()).sum()` gave the exact same result; so did `arr.par_chunks(1024 * 1024).map(|e| e.iter().sum::<u32>()).sum()`.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! Indeed, the single-threaded version on rust is more optimized, because of my stupid mistake I didn't notice it. Thanks for the story about memory bandwidth, now everything is clear.

Comment: >I don't think that the OpenMP version is faster than the rayon version

It is possible that C++ compiler has specific optimizations for OpenMP.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros No matter what optimizations it does, it won't beat ram bandwidth.